# Unable to transfer from a contract to another contract

Tags: web3js, contract-development, truffle, contract-debugging

I was trying to learn how smart contract interaction by implementing a bank contract and a client contract. The end user create a `Client` contract. Then, he use the `Client` contract to deposit or withdraw money from `Bank` contract.

**An error occurred**

However, I was not able to transfer the money from `Client` contract to the `Bank` contract, and the prompt throw error when the user called `addDeposit()` method in `Client`. The prompt says `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Below is the `TestContract.js`

```
const Bank = artifacts.require("Bank");
var Client = artifacts.require("Client");
// ether = 10**18;

contract("TestContracts", function(accounts) {
    const alice = accounts[1];
    it("add deposit using client contract", async () => {
        const bank = await Bank.deployed();
        const client = await Client.deployed(bank.address, alice); //the owner of the contract is alice

        client.addFund({ from: alice, value: web3.utils.toWei("30","ether") });

        balance = web3.utils.fromWei(await client.checkBalance());
        assert(balance, 30, "balance of the contract wrong");

        await client.addDeposit(5);
        let deposit = web3.utils.fromWei(await client.checkDeposit()); //ERROR HERE!!!!
        assert(deposit, 5, "balance of the contract wrong");
    })
```

Here is the `Client` contract

```
contract Client {
    address owner; // the client contract connect with the account who creates it
    Bank bank; // the bank that this client contract connected with

    constructor (address _referBank, address _owner) public payable {
        owner = _owner;
        bank = Bank(_referBank);
        bank.enroll(address(this));
    }

    function isClientActive() public view returns(bool) {
        return bank.isClientActive(address(this));
    }

    function addFund() public payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "only owner are allow to send money to client contract");
    }

    function addDeposit(uint amount) public {
        bank.transfer(amount);
    }

    function withdraw(uint amount) public payable {
        bank.withdraw(amount);
    }

    function checkDeposit() public view returns(uint) {
        return bank.checkDeposit(address(this));
    }

    function checkBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    // transfer the balance from the client's contract to the owner account
    function () public payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "only owner are allow to send money to client contract");
    }
}
```

Below is the `Bank` contract

```
contract Bank {
    struct Client {
        uint deposit;
        bool active;
    }

    address owner;
    mapping(address => Client) public clientList;
    uint clientCounter;

    constructor() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 30 ether, "Initial funding of 30 ether required for rewards");
        /* Set the owner to the creator of this contract */
        owner = msg.sender;
        clientCounter = 0;
    }

    function enroll(address _addr) public {
        clientList[_addr].deposit = 0;
        clientList[_addr].active = true;
        clientCounter++;
    }

    function isClientActive(address _addr) public view returns(bool) {
        return clientList[_addr].active;
    }

    function getClientCounter() public view returns(uint) {
        return clientCounter;
    }

    // add the deposit to the sender account
    function addDeposit() public payable {
        if (clientList[msg.sender].active != true) {
            revert("the client's address does not exist");
        } else {
            clientList[msg.sender].deposit += msg.value;
        }
    }

    // transfer the amount of ether to the provided address
    function withdraw(uint amount) public payable {
        if (clientList[msg.sender].deposit < amount) {
            revert("not enough deposit to make the withdraw");
        } else {
            clientList[msg.sender].deposit -= amount;
            msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        }
    }

    // return the deposit of the provide address
    function checkDeposit(address _addr) public view returns (uint) {
        return clientList[_addr].deposit;
    }

    // received money from the client contract
    function () public payable {
        if (!isClientActive(msg.sender)) {
            revert("client does not exist");
        } else {
            clientList[msg.sender].deposit += msg.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the function (in the Client contract):

```
function addDeposit(uint amount) public {
    bank.transfer(amount);
  }
```

Because `bank` is not an address. You can save the bank address in the ocnstructor and use it to do the transfer or better, use the `addDeposit` function of `bank` in the Client, like this:

```
function addDeposit(uint amount) public {
    bank.addDeposit.value(amount)();
  }
```

I test it in remix and it works well.

Hope this helps you.